# Trying to detect what node was tapped on scenekit

Tags: ios, iphone, scenekit, scnnode

This is my problem. I have create an object on maya that have the following hierarchy:

```
bigButton
   | 
   |--  redDome
   |       |
   |       |-- polySurface1
   |       |__ polySurface2
   |
   |--  greenDome
          |
          |-- polySurface3
          |__ polySurface4
```

I convert that to DAE and import it on SceneKit. Two more nodes are added to the hierarchy by Xcode. The hierarchy is now:

```
bitButton Reference
   |
   |_ referenceRoot
          |
          |
          |__ bigButton 
                   | 
                   |--  redDome
                   |       |
                   |       |-- polySurface1
                   |       |__ polySurface2
                   |
                   |--  greenDome
                           |
                           |-- polySurface3
                           |__ polySurface4
```

Now I touch the button and I am trying to determine if the button was tapped. The only node that matters to me is `bigButton`. WHen I tap the object and use this method:

```
- (void) handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognize
{
    // retrieve the SCNView
    SCNView *scnView = (SCNView *)self.view;

    // check what nodes are tapped
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognize locationInView:scnView];
    NSArray *hitResults = [scnView hitTest:p options:nil];

    // check that we clicked on at least one object
    if([hitResults count] > 0){
        // retrieved the first clicked object
        SCNHitTestResult *result = [hitResults objectAtIndex:0];
```

`result.node` tells me that the node touched was `polySurface1` or `polySurface2` whatever. It will never tell me that `bigButton` was tapped because that is just a node, not a surface.

OK, I can use `parentNode` to detect the parent's node but this is stupid because `result.node` can be on different hierarchy levels above or below `bigButton`. Is this the only lame mode to do that? To transverse the hierarchy searching for the correct node or is is there a beautiful way?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only node that matters to me is `bigButton`.

If by that you mean that you'll never be interested in knowing that any other node was hit, then you should take a look at the `SCNHitTestRootNodeKey` hit-testing option.

Specifying `bigButton` as the root node implies that getting *any* hit-test result means that `bigButton` was hit, without having to do any check.

Comment: I mean that `bigButton` is composed of several descendant members. Any touch on any of these members should be detected as `bigButton` being touched. If this can be done like you say, can you give an example of the code I have to use? Apple documentation, as usual, is useless.

Comment: I have used these options and it gives me a `nil` `hitResults` ... `@{SCNHitTestRootNodeKey : bigButton,                                                    SCNHitTestIgnoreChildNodesKey : @(YES)}`

Comment: you must not set `SCNHitTestIgnoreChildNodesKey` to `YES`. This would mean that exactly one node (`bigButton`) will be tested, but as you said this node has no geometry and can't be hit. Use only `SCNHitTestRootNodeKey`, it will restrict hit-testing to `bigButton` **and** its child nodes. This way you can be sure that if there's a result, it comes from node under `bigButton`.

Comment: sorry, I did that but it stills continue to detect `polySurface1`, `polySurface2`, `polySurface3`... I want this: the user taps on `polySurface1`, code detects "user tapped bigButton"... user taps on `polySurface2`, code detects "user tapped bigButton". Everything that is part of `bigButton` should be detected as `bigButton` not `polySurface1`, etc.

Comment: you can't have a `SCNHitTestResult` lie about which node was hit. But because you restricted hit-testing to `bigButton` and its child nodes, there's no further logic to implement. Getting any result means that something under `bigButton` was hit. So it's exactly what you want.

Comment: ah, I see, duuuh!! Please add this information to your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: For posterity I was having an issue where a SCNView's hitTest wasn't finding a node that was behind another node, even though `SCNHitTestOption.firstFoundOnly` was false. Restricting the test to the node I wanted to find via `SCNHitTestOption.rootNode` did the trick.